# How to get a list of all .svg files on Wikipedia.org and commons.wikimedia.org?

Tags: search, wikipedia, wikimedia-commons

I do have a very slow internet connection. Nonetheless it would be fast enough to download a list of the files I'm looking for: I want a list of all .svg files on Wikipedia.org and commons.wikimedia.org. (And later on after that of all svg-files on the other wikipedia and wikimedia pages.)

But my internet connection is not fast enough to find the right search-words by trial and error: It's absolutly tedious to do trial-and-error with 64kbit/sec.

Could anyone point me to the right page on wikipedia or commons.wikimedia where I could start such a search and which keywords and settings to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you also asked this at the [Wikipedia Help Desk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Help_desk) (which, in my opinion, is really a better resource for Wikipedia questions).

The answer you got, which seems to suit your needs, was:

> Over at [dumps.wikimedia.org](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/commonswiki/20150325/) is a link to a compressed "all-titles.gz" file containing the names of *all* pages at Commons. That would take an hour or two to download at 64kbit/sec, but you'd then be able to grep the .svg files. The corresponding list for other wikis could be reached via [the dumps index page](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/backup-index-bydb.html). -- John of Reading

([Wikipedia diff](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Wikipedia:Help_desk&oldid=655294697))

Comment: That's right. That's what I really wanted to have. I can't upvote though. (Not enough rep.)

Answer (score 3):

If you use [the search query `File: intitle:svg`](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&profile=default&search=File%3A+intitle%3Asvg&fulltext=Search), you will get all files that have "svg" in their name. This will include files that do not have the `.svg` extension, but have `svg` in their name, but those should be rare.

Comment: That's good, too. Tyvm